# does Windows azure website instances make my application run in different instances?

Tags: jsf, azure, javabeans

I am developing a website using Java Server Faces and i have Application scoped Managed beans where i keep some dynamic data related to the whole application and i am hosting it on windows azure.

i am hosting it using tomcat with azure websites. but the problem is that i want to know when i put my  website to run in more than 1 instances will it ruin my application scope, i mean that will each instance have its own application scope?? which is not what i want. if so how can i solve it ??

Comment: I'm not sure how that forms a problem. Can you give a concrete example? Chances are likely that it concerns user data which should actually be stored in session scope instead. That can in turn be distributed.

Comment: the data that I'm saving is logged in users , so that one user cannot log in from two sessions at the same time ,if they log in to a second session while other session is logged in, with the same account, the older session will be logged out automatically , are there any other ways to do this rather than this approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Azure Websites, when you run in more than one instance, each instance runs on a different VM (free tier is the exception, as everything runs in a single instance).

I don't see how your application scope would span across multiple virtual machines.